# How to get all elements in nested collection with streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class which contains different nested collections, now I want to receive all the elements of the nested collections, concrete I want to collect all the StrokePoints of the collections. I can solve it with "old" java but how to do it with streams?

```
    int strokesCounter = 0;
    List<StrokePoint> pointList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!strokesData.getListOfSessions().isEmpty()) {
        for (SessionStrokes session : strokesData.getListOfSessions()) {
            List<Strokes> strokes = session.getListOfStrokes();
            for (Strokes stroke : strokes) {
                strokesCounter++;
                List<StrokePoint> points = stroke.getListOfStrokePoints();
                pointList.addAll(stroke.getListOfStrokePoints());        
            }
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to fill the pointList with the stream functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Flattening the nested data is pretty simple:

```
List<StrokePoint> pointList = strokesData.getListOfSessions()
        .streams()
        .map(SessionStrokes::getListOfStrokes)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Strokes::getListOfStrokePoints)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Collecting the stroke count along the way is more tricky, and somewhat controversial. You could create a

```
AtomicInteger strokesCounter = new AtomicInteger();
```

and increment it just after the first `flatMap`:

```
.peek(strokesCounter::incrementAndGet)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) twice:

```
List<StrokePoint> pointList = strokesData.getListOfSessions().stream()
        .flatMap(session -> session.getListOfStrokes().stream())
        .flatMap(strokes -> strokes.getListOfStrokePoints().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need to count the strokes list you can split this into two parts and use `List.size()`:

```
List<Strokes> strokesList = strokesData.getListOfSessions().stream()
        .flatMap(session -> session.getListOfStrokes().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
int strokesCounter = strokesList.size();
List<StrokePoint> pointList = strokesList.stream()
        .flatMap(strokes -> strokes.getListOfStrokePoints().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively you can increment an `AtomicInteger` in `flatMap()`:

```
final AtomicInteger strokesCounter = new AtomicInteger();
List<StrokePoint> pointList = strokesData.getListOfSessions().stream()
        .flatMap(session -> {
            List<Strokes> strokes = session.getListOfStrokes();
            strokesCounter.addAndGet(strokes.size());
            return strokes.stream();
        })
        .flatMap(strokes -> strokes.getListOfStrokePoints().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or with `peek()`:

```
final AtomicInteger strokesCounter = new AtomicInteger();
List<StrokePoint> pointList = strokesData.getListOfSessions().stream()
        .flatMap(session -> session.getListOfStrokes().stream())
        .peek(i -> strokesCounter.incrementAndGet())
        .flatMap(strokes -> strokes.getListOfStrokePoints().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the primary aim is to solve for collecting the `List<StrokePoint>`, you can perform it using the `flatMap` operation as:

```
List<StrokePoint> points = strokesData.getListOfSessions()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(ss -> ss.getListOfStrokes().stream()
                .flatMap(s -> s.getListOfStrokePoints().stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alongside, the count of `Stroke`s can also be evaluated using the streams by summing the size of the lists as:

```
long strokeCount = strokesData.getListOfSessions()
        .stream()
        .mapToLong(ss -> ss.getListOfStrokes().size())
        .sum();
```

---

To merge these operations, you can construct a `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` while reducing the entries as:

```
AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Stream<StrokePoint>> reduce = strokesData.getListOfSessions()
        .stream()
        .map(ss -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ss.getListOfStrokes().size(),
                ss.getListOfStrokes()
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getListOfStrokePoints().stream())))
        .reduce(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(1, Stream.empty()),
                (e1, e2) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                        Integer.sum(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey()),
                        Stream.concat(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue())));
```

Using this entry, you can attain the count of `Stroke`s and the list of `StrokePoint`s as :

```
long strokeCount = reduce.getKey();
List<StrokePoint> strokePoints = reduce.getValue().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about side-effects, this will do it (but both the other answers at the time of writing are infinitely more readable):

```
    Entry<Integer, List<StrokePoint>> summary = //
            strokesData.getListOfSessions()
                       .stream()
                       .flatMap(session -> session.getListOfStrokes().stream())
                       .map(strokes -> new SimpleEntry<>(1, strokes.getListOfStrokePoints()))
                       .reduce((l1, l2) -> {
                           int count = l1.getKey() + l2.getKey();

                           List<StrokePoint> list = l1.getValue();
                           list.addAll(l2.getValue());

                           return new SimpleEntry<>(count, list);
                       })
                       .orElse(new SimpleEntry<>(0, Collections.emptyList()));

    strokesCounter = summary.getKey();
    pointList = summary.getValue();
```

EDITING to add validation:

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int strokesCounter = 0;
        List<StrokePoint> pointList = new ArrayList<>();
        StrokesData strokesData = new StrokesData();

        SessionStrokes sessionStrokes = new SessionStrokes();
        strokesData.sessionStrokes.add(sessionStrokes);

        Strokes s1 = new Strokes();
        sessionStrokes.strokesList.add(s1);

        s1.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());
        s1.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());

        Strokes s2 = new Strokes();
        sessionStrokes.strokesList.add(s2);

        s2.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());
        s2.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());
        s2.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());
        s2.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());
        s2.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());
        s2.strokePoints.add(new StrokePoint());

        Entry<Integer, List<StrokePoint>> summary = //
                strokesData.getListOfSessions()
                           .stream()
                           .flatMap(session -> session.getListOfStrokes()
                                                      .stream())
                           .map(strokes -> new SimpleEntry<>(1, strokes.getListOfStrokePoints()))
                           .reduce((l1, l2) -> {
                               int count = l1.getKey() + l2.getKey();

                               List<StrokePoint> list = l1.getValue();
                               list.addAll(l2.getValue());

                               return new SimpleEntry<>(count, list);
                           })
                           .orElse(new SimpleEntry<>(0, Collections.emptyList()));

        strokesCounter = summary.getKey();
        pointList = summary.getValue();

        System.out.println(strokesCounter);
        System.out.println(pointList);
    }
}

class StrokesData {

    List<SessionStrokes> sessionStrokes = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<SessionStrokes> getListOfSessions() {
        return sessionStrokes;
    }
}

class SessionStrokes {

    List<Strokes> strokesList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Strokes> getListOfStrokes() {
        return strokesList;
    }

}

class Strokes {

    List<StrokePoint> strokePoints = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<StrokePoint> getListOfStrokePoints() {
        return strokePoints;
    }
}

class StrokePoint {
}
```

Comment: You're summing the wrong count. Might as well do `strokesCounter = pointList.size()`.

Comment: @shmosel, code appears to work - added an edit with some stub implementation of types - and `strokesCounter == 2` while `pointList.size() == 8`... (Seriously) please lmk what I'm doing wrong, this is something I'm going to obsess over otherwise!!